# Integral representation in the case of two variable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, we have the follwoing integral representation : for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ :
$$f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b f'(t)dt.$$
Now if we consider $g\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ do we have similar result for the mapping $g(f(.),.)$ ?

$$g(f(b),b)-g(f(a),a)= \int_a^b f'(t)\partial_x g(f(t),t)+\partial_y g(f(t),t) dt$$
This is my suggestion.

Comment: Your $f(t)$ in the integrand should be $f'(t)$

Comment: @RhysHughes Yes

Comment: Look at the path $\gamma: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$, $t\mapsto (f(t), t)$. Then you have
$$(g\circ \gamma)(b) - (g\circ\gamma)(a) = \int_a^b (g\circ \gamma)'(t)\,dt $$

where $(g\circ\gamma)'(t) = (\partial_1 g)(f(t),t) \cdot f'(t) + (\partial_2g)(f(t), t)$ by the chain rule.

Comment: @s.harp Thank you, that means that my suggestion is true.